# Make list value selected - sencha touch

Tags: list, sencha-touch, selecteditem

I have overlay in which I am having one list component.
   I am selecting multiple list items from that.
   I am pressing OK button and my overlay is getting disappeared.

Now What I want is :

When I open that overlay again , I want those previously selected items highlighted.

I want to do this in sencha touch.

Comment: do you have problem in getting and setting selected values or storing selected values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open your overlay again, previously selected items should be shown or highlighted.

As per my understanding, When you click on Ok button, You would be passing selected values as extra parameter in store to load it again.

so, when you open that overlay again, you would have those extraparams in the store...so, you can do below things. I am sure, It will work.

`var store = Ext.getStore('storeId'),`

`selectedItems[],`

`selectedRec,`

`selectedRecs = [],`

`extraparameter = store.getProxy().extraParameters;`

You can get selected transaction types like this.

`selectedItems = extraparameter.selectedItems`

`Ext.Array.each(selectedItems , function(selectedItem) {`

`selectedRec = multiSelect.getStore().findRecord('transaction_type', transactiontype);`
`selectedRecs.push(selectedRec);`
});`

Thanks !